# How to run javascript selenium function using a html button?

Tags: javascript

This code works fine but I need to run this script on a html button means when the button is clicked then this function get executed!!!

```
async function example() {
    let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser("chrome").build();
    await driver.get("https://google.com");  
}
example();
```

I tried this but not working,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Javascript Testing</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/Javascript">
        async function example()
        {
        const {Builder, By, Key, util} = require("selenium-webdriver")
        let driver = new Builder().forBrowser("chrome").build();
        driver.get("https://google.com");
        driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Selenium",KEY.RETURN);
        }
    </script>
    <button onClick="example()">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Error:

```
index.html Uncaught ReferenceError: example is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick
```

and, I also tried it with external js but it still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

selenium-webdriver cannot run inside a web browser, the APIs it needs are not available.

You would need to rewrite the JS so it runs in Node.js.

If you wanted to access it from a web browser, then you would need to write a web service front end for it.

You could then access that web service from the browser with, for example, `fetch`.